# textview.getLineCount always 0 in android

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to dynamically resize my textview but getlinecount() method always returns me 0 even after settext() and invalidate(). I'm using the following code:

```java
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}

holder.text2.setText(arr2[position]);
holder.text2.invalidate();

int lineCnt = holder.text2.getLineCount();
```

holder is a static class as follows:

```java
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text2;
}
```

holder contains non null text2 and the content set is also non null.

Answer (score 93):

I know this question is quite old, but in case anyone comes here looking for the actual answer:

```
holder.text2.setText(arr2[position]);
holder.text2.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int lineCnt = holder.text2.getLineCount();
        // Perform any actions you want based on the line count here.
    }
});
```

Comment: Also TextView needs to be VISIBLE or INVISIBLE for this method. When its GONE, it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it right to use thread inside android b'coz i have been advised that it is the bad practice to use thread for this task

Comment: In my experience the post() method sometimes is still called *before* the layout pass. It happens randomly and not often, but in those cases we still get 0 value for line count even inside the mentioned Runnable.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is about 9 years old and a lot has changed in that time. I no longer work on Android so I can't tell you the latest way to do this.

Answer (score 27):

In order to fix this issue apply the following lines:

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (textView.getLineCount() > 1) {
            textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

The `OnGlobalLayoutListener` will be called after every change to the `TextView` (after measuring it, drawing it, ..). Here you can catch changes to your `TextView` before it'll be drawn to the screen and do whatever you need with it.

The last line in the code is to remove the listener, it's important since we don't want to continue catching each layout change.

Comment: What is `mediaAtomLayout`?

Comment: I guess mediaAtomLayout here repsresents our textview

Answer (score 24):

It should be done on UI Thread by post method.

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.v("Line count: ", textView.getLineCount()+"");
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, but how does it work ? Bcoz, im setting the text to textview only in UI thread and without this textView.post, why doesn't it return me the linecount?

Answer (score 10):

getLineCount() will give you the correct number of lines only after a layout pass. That means the TextView must have been drawn at least once. I assume that at this point of time your Textview is not drawn hence you are getting 0 as the line count

Comment: Thanx Rahul.. That's right, but I'm afraid wheather where to set this height if even not after setText().

Comment: I am not sure where this code has been placed as of now. But if you have placed it under getview you text is shown/drawn only after you return the view object for that position

Answer (score 4):

actually TextView.getLineCount() rely on TextView.mLayout.getLineCount
but TextView.mLayout is lazy init before onMeasure, you can do like this:

```
       if (holder.contentTV.getLayout() == null) {
            holder.contentTV.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    holder.contentTV.getLineCount();
                    holder.contentTV.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.contentTV.getLineCount();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I create an extension for simple use:

```
/**
 * Function for detect when layout completely configure.
 */
fun View.afterLayoutConfiguration(func: () -> Unit) {
    viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            viewTreeObserver?.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            func()
        }
    })
}
```

Example of use:

```
textView.afterLayoutConfiguration {
    val lineCount = textView.lineCount
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I made an asynctask class and did my getLineCount()-related tasks in its onPostExecute method.

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new myAsyncTask().execute(null, null, null);
}

private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // It's okay to leave this as it is
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //DO YOUR TASK HERE, getLineCount(), etc.       
    }
}
```

Comment: If any down-votes, probably because using a timer to wait for layout to be complete is risky, since there is no guarantee that layout will be complete when your async task runs.  Watching for layout/drawing related events would be better (I don't have any code yet or I would post it).

Comment: Risky? It's not risky, it's just wrong!