# Android : myTextView.getLineCount() / getHeight() = 0?

Tags: android, textview, getline

I want to get the height or at least the line count of my text view programatically, but the log says 0. What is wrong ? Here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_off);

    titreOff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.offTitre);
    titreOff.setText("some text"); // displays 2 lines of text with the font size I used
    System.out.println(titreOff.getLineCount() + " and " + titreOff.getHeight());
}
```

Thanks for your advices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [textview.getLineCount always 0 in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528790/textview-getlinecount-always-0-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `onCreate()`, your `TextView` has not had a layout pass and so currently has a zero width and height. There are a few solutions if you would like to get the dimensions of your `TextView`:

1. Add an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to your `TextView`'s `ViewTreeObserver`. (e.g. `titreOff.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)` and handle your changes there).
2. Override `TextView` and handle your special case by overriding `onLayout()` (in which you will have the dimensions of your `TextView` as parameters.

Alternatively, what is the end goal of your measurements? If you can give some specifics, there may be an easier solution than any of this.

Comment: As a warning, don't make my mistake and make layout changes within the listener -- this will cause it to re-enter the listener infinitely. If you *do* need to make layout changes within the listener, you should remove the listener within itself (i.e. `titreOff.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)` within the `onGlobalLayout()` method.

Comment: Option #1 does not work reliably (it's common for getLineCount to return 0 inside OnGlobalLayout despite the view containing text). You'll probably need to go with option #2.

Answer (score 2):

Your app doesn't know the actual size of `TextView` while doing `onCreate()` method. The solution is to move your output here:

```
onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) {
        titreOff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.offTitre);
        System.out.println(titreOff.getLineCount() + 
        " and " + titreOff.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do but when I do that, it returns the correct value only when I exit the view and not when I enter it...

Answer (score 1):

`setText()` doesn't immediately update the `TextView`, it just invalidates it. The new text will be set only on the next repaint. If you try to get the height before you will get the old one.

Instead, you should subclass `TextView`, override [`onSizeChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and you will be notified each time the size of your `TextView` changed.