# Add text to the beginning of a new line, if the text is automatically wrap

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

At the outset, I would like to apologize for my English :).

I have a String with long text. I display it in a TextView. If the text is automatically wrapped to new line, I want to add "\t" at the beginning of the new line. I don't know how do it. Any ideas?

E.g.

```
String text = "1. abcdefghij\n\tklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

Display:
1. abcdefghij
   klmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

But if:

```
String text = "1. abcdefghij\n\tklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

Display:
1. abcdefghij
   klmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

I want:

```
1. abcdefghij
   klmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF
   GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: If you just need it to move the text forward, why don't you use paddingLeft on the textview?

Comment: I need move text ONLY if text is automatically wrap.

Comment: So it's not indented on the first line, only on the second and any consecutive lines?

Comment: The indentations are randomly, depending on the length of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the lines of your TextView and if there are more than 1 insert a "\t".

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528790/textview-getlinecount-always-0-in-android) it's shown how to count the lines although is not an obvious question.

You also need to take into account if the tab is already inserted, because could be inserted more than one \b.

Comment: This is my code: http://pastebin.com/Dg5apb4F
In array "test" are the lines of text. Run() should write out the "Get Count." after each "Number of lines:...", but Run() work only after all, like in link. Xxxxx is my lines of text, which is well printed.