# How to check if a TextView is Scrollable

Tags: android, textview

I made a `TextView` scrollable if it has more than 5 lines. Now I want dynamically in my java code to detect if the same `TextView` is scrollable or can scroll so I can change the visibility of a view below it.

I tried:

```
textView.setText(description);
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

if(textView.getLineCount() > 5)
{
   view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

but the `textView.getLineCount()` is equal to 0.

Also tried the function `canScrollHorizontally(int direction)` but Google's documentation doesn't say which parameter should I use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12037459/2649012

Comment: I'm calling the getLineCount() after the text is rendered

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528790/textview-getlinecount-always-0-in-android this might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You getting ZERO because you try to take a result in non-UI thread.

Try

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

    int lineCount = textView.getLineCount();
    if(lineCount >=5)
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: yup that made for me. I was going to post that as an answer but you were faster ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use a thread in order to get lineCount:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(textView.getLineCount() == 0){   
    }
    textview_lineCount = textView.getLineCount(); 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your `TextView` is a child of a `ScrollView` and you want to **automatically** scroll your `TextView` after it has been appended and now contains more text, than it can display, you may do the following:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someTextView);
t.append("Some text");

ScrollView s;
if (s.canScrollVertically(1)) {
    logScroll(s);
}

private void logScroll(final ScrollView s) {
    s.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
}
```