# Setting LayoutParams via post method in List View adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to set a margin in a text view and padding in a linear layout in a list view adapter.  Basically, if the text view has 2 or less lines of text I am creating a margin/padding for that list item.

Here is the code:

```
public class StockCountListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StockCountItem> {

private TextView txtProduct;
private LinearLayout llStockCountItem;

public StockCountListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<StockCountItem> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_count_list_item, parent, false);

    txtProduct = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stock_count_item_product);
    llStockCountItem = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ll_stock_count_item);

    StockCountItem item = getItem(position);

    txtProduct.setText(item.Product);

    llStockCountItem.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
        public void run() {
           if (txtProduct.getLineCount() <= 2) {

               llStockCountItem.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);

               LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 7);
               params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 10);
               txtProduct.setLayoutParams(params);

           }
       }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

The margin/padding is applied when the list is scrolled, but not when the list is first displayed or on orientation change.

How can I get it to apply the margin/padding on activity load or orientation change?

Comment: You need to save the padding numbers in the bundle inside  onSaveInstanceState and read the numbers inside onCreate. look here:
:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.htm

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough - The margin/padding is not being applied when the list is first displayed either - I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

**Handling Runtime Changes**

When Screen orientation such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (`onDestroy(`) is called, followed by `onCreate()`). The restart behavior is designed to help your application adapt to new configurations by automatically reloading your application with alternative resources that match the new device configuration.

To properly handle a restart, it is important that your activity restores its previous state through the normal Activity `lifecycle`, in which Android calls `onSaveInstanceState()` before it destroys your activity so that you can save data about the application state. You can then restore the state during `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

- [**`GRAVITY`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)

in code

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 7);
params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 10);
params.gravity = Gravity.FILL; // this is where i come in
txtProduct.setLayoutParams(params);
txtProduct.invalidate(); // edits
txtProduct.requestLayout();//edits
```

*the type of `Gravity` is up to you now* with rotation you need to override `onOnrientationChanged()` (something like that) and call that same code there

Edit

base on your post runnable code i am thinking of a workaround, i do not think it will work but worth it.. since `txtProduct.getLineCount()` returns 0 after layout pass, i am improvising

```
if(txtProduct.getLineCount()==0){ //if false you run your previous code without post
     int textSize = txtProduct.getTextSize()/2,mw,lines;
     // for the textsize i am thinking of a rectangle
     if(txtProduct.getMeasuredWidth() > 0) //if this line checks out 0 the code is trash

  //assume none where zero
  int fillW = textSize * txtProduct.getText().toString().length();
  if(fillW > mw){ //my logic here is we have more than one line
     if(fillW / mw > -1){ //
      lines = fillW/mv;
       if(fillW%mv !=0){// it is not a factor which means there is another line trending
           lines++;
           // now add your normal code here without post to check if lines is what you want
       }
     }
   }
 }else{ //add your code without post
```

see if this works,

Comment: I tried `Gravity.LEFT` and `Gravity.FILL` but unfortunately it still doesn't apply the margin/padding until I begin scrolling down the list

Comment: i am certain it should work, try gravities with center or center horinzontal etc and see @BenKleywegt and quick question why are you putting that line of code in a runnable? post? any reason?

Comment: I put it in a post because of `txtProduct.getLineCount()` ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528790/textview-getlinecount-always-0-in-android)).  I tried some different gravities but it still isn't working.

Comment: can you please check some edit i have made and see if it actually works @BenKleywegt

Comment: unfortunately `txtProduct.getMeasuredWidth()` will return zero because the TextView has 0 width and layout_weight set i.e. `android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="7"` so the width isn't known until after the layout is drawn - requiring a post runnable to get the measured width.  I can't really set a fixed width because I want the layout to scale out to both large and small screens

Comment: hmm your question seems interesting, try this last one then i am out of tricks, use my first codes as you did and this time add invalidate and maybe requestLayout() and see if it works, i will edit it an put it in@BenKleywegt

Comment: @EIItz I think that's close - I tried those methods previously but didn't have any success but I'll keep experimenting tomorrow