# EditeText Android change Text

Tags: android, android-edittext

when I am trying to change text on EditText by calling setText, the function called getLineCount on editText is always 0 after that, why it doesn't change?

Comment: Please see the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529765/16234182

Comment: Does this answer your question? [textview.getLineCount always 0 in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528790/textview-getlinecount-always-0-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call getLineCount immediately then it will be always zero because TextView needs some time to draw itself completely.

Try to call this after setText :

```
editText.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("Count", editText.getLineCount().toString());
    }
});
```